# Django : best place to store constants used in view and Celery tasks

Tags: django, architecture

I'm looking for advice regarding project structure in my Django app. I want to define a constant that is used both in a view and in a background task (Celery to be specific), but I am not sure where this should be placed.

The constant defines the number of records to be shown to the user. My model represents an image, and only the recent 100 records need to be displayed on the page. Older records can be deleted, and there is a separate Celery task that cleans up such records on a weekly basis.

I have defined this `100` as `NUM_RECORDS_TO_SHOW` in my model class, but I am not sure if this is the best place, since I am exposing my model to the business logic. Defining this constant in my view seems also a bad idea, as this could lead to circular imports.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to define any such constants in my `settings.py` module if its global for the project.

```
# settings.py

NUM_RECORDS_TO_SHOW = 100 # or you even can fetch it from env
```

Access this variable in ***anywhere your code*** as below

```
# tasks.py or views.py

from django.conf import settings

print(settings.NUM_RECORDS_TO_SHOW) #  this will return the value `100`
```